# A problem with too many counting required

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> We have $10$ bags of candies each with $10$ colorful candies    It is
>   known that **at least** $1$ of the bags contains **exactly** $5$ red
>   candies
>
> We get $1$ candy from **each** bag what is the probability that we get
>   an even($0$ is considered even) number of red candies?

I assumed that each bag that doesn't contain exactly $5$ red candies contain 1 candy of each color(1 red, 1 blue, 1 green...) because I didn't think its possible to solve it without it, but even with this assumption I got stuck pretty quickly.

My question is do we need that assumption at all(cause I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to work without it)?
And more importantly how to solve such a problem with so many cases to consider (0,2,4,6,8,10 -> each of these cases could be a question of its own)

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without knowing something about the color distribution.  I don't see why the assumption you make is the most natural one.  If, say, you assume that every bag is half red then the answer is $.5$.

Comment: @lulu I thought its more reasonable to assume the more common case of 1 of each candy color in each bag, although I have been told that we do not need any more data on that question which I find pretty odd, the only hint is to use conditional probability and define a variable as the condition

Comment: I was wrong, you don't need more information.  I posted a solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhat unexpectedly, it turns out that you don't need any information about the distribution of colors in the remaining bags.  This, of course, is a property of symmetry...if you replace the $5$ in your problem with anything else, then the question can not be answered without additional information.

Suppose we know that bag $\#1$ contains exactly $5$. Of course the probability is exactly $.5$ that we get a red from that bag.  What about the $9$ others?  Well, let $p_E$ be the probability that we get an even number (from the remaining $9$), and $p_O$ the probability that we get an odd.  Of course $p_E+p_O=1$  so your answer is $$\frac 12\times p_E+\frac 12\times p_O=\frac 12\times (p_E+p_O)=\frac 12$$

Comment: thanks just to be sure, your equation in words means: we either get 1 non red from bag #$1$ $(0.5)$ and even number of reds from the others or we get 1 red from bag #$1$ $(0.5)$ and odd number of reds from the others?

Comment: also another question (which I think needs to be in a new comment to not mess up with chars limit): how did we know that there is an equal chance to draw $pE$ or $pO$? 
And we assumed that bag #1 contains exactly 5 but maybe bag #1 and bag #2 contains exactly 5. will it change the solution?

Comment: We don't know that $p_E=p_O$.  One of them could be $0$.  All we know is that they add to $1$ (because you have to get either an even or an odd number).  Doesn't matter if other bags have exactly $5$, we only need one.    As to your first comment, you have it right...either you get an odd number from the nine and then get a red one from bag $1$, or you get an even number from the nine and then get a non-red one from bag $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as stated is not well posed, as we don't know what is the probability that a bag contain exactly $n$ candies. We could have for example that each candy has probability $\tfrac{1}{p}$ of being red for some $p$, or that the probability for a bag to contain exactly $n$ red candies is exactly $\tfrac{1}{10}$, and those two cases would give drastically different answers.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Thanks, edited.

Comment: If we do assume that the chance of the "non-special" (not the 5 red bags) bags to be $\tfrac{1}{10}$ how could we solve it now?